# res.render an ember route with express

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, routes

I currently have a webapp using Express, Node, Ember, and Mongo. Ember app resides in a project folder (./public/index.html) in the root of the node/express install. I have express set to serve static files from the public directory and render index.html to any get requests so the ember app is accessible.

I have a route/view in my Ember app that has a form that accepts a file upload, this form's action is a post request to an express route that performs calculations and queries a local mysql database with updates. The function works fine but at the end of the .post express function when I res.json or res.send the response appears in the browser window and clears out my ember view.

I assume the correct way to handle this is to res.render('view',{data:'Finished processing file'});

then display the data value on the ember template. Question is how can I render an ember view with express. I added express-handlebars to my project and setup the view engine correctly but I don't know how to associate ember views with express so it knows how to render the correct view with response data.

hbs file for the ember view

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
  <h2 class="toolTitle">Reactivate SKUs</h2>
  <p class="lead">CSV Should Contain 1 Column (SKU) Only</p>
  <form action="/tools/sku/reactivate" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="center-block" type="file" name="csvdata">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-danger">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

router.js(express router)

```
var quotes = require('../api/quote');
var cors = require('cors');
var sku = require('../api/tools/sku');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var util = require("util");
var fs = require("fs"); 

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}

module.exports = function(router){
    router.route('/quotes').post(cors(corsOptions),function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        quotes.addQuote(req,res);
    }).get(cors(corsOptions),function(req,res){
        quotes.getAllQuotes(req,res);
    });
    router.route('*').get(cors(corsOptions), function(req,res){
        res.sendFile('public/index.html',{root:'./'});
    });
    router.route('/tools/sku/reactivate').post(upload.single('csvdata'),function(req,res){
        console.log('handing request over to sku.reactivate');
        sku.reactivate(req,res);
    });
};
```

sku.js express function

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var csv = require('csv-parse');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

//mysql setup
const connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'rugs_remote2',
        password : 'ofbiz',
        database : 'rugs_prd2',
        multipleStatements: true
    }
);
connection.connect();


module.exports.reactivate = function(req,res){
    //define mysql query function for once readStream emits end event
    function reactivationQuery(arr){
    console.log(arr);

       const queryString = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET SALES_DISCONTINUATION_DATE = NULL WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (?)";
       connection.query(queryString,arr,function(err,rows,fields){
            console.log(rows,fields);
            if(err){
                console.log('Error running sku.reactivate module error is: '+err);
            }
            res.send('DONE');
        });
    }

    //define array for holding csv data in this case skus
    const skuArray = [];
    //define filesystem readstream from uploaded file
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path).pipe(csv());
    //push csv data to array ignoring headers to skuArray
    readStream.on('data', function(chunk){
        if(chunk[0] !== 'SKU'){
            skuArray.push(chunk[0]);
        }
    });
    //error handling
    readStream.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file stream [ERROR] '+ err);
        res.send('Error while processing file');
    });
    //once read is finished map skuArray to usable string for IN Clause
    readStream.on('end',function(){
       let stringifyArray = skuArray;
       stringifyArray = [stringifyArray]; 
       reactivationQuery(stringifyArray);
    });

}
```

Comment: I think this is more about how you are running the ember app and express app--you will want to treat the express app an api running by itself, and the ember app with `ember s --proxy=localhost:3000` (or whichever port). That enables the ember app's requests to go through express in development

Comment: that's the odd thing I am proxying ember to the node server. but I still get the response rendered in browser instead of just returning data to the ember template that made the post request.

Comment: Ah, you're doing a regular form post which is taking you out of ember and to whatever comes back from /tools/sky/reactive. You should use an ember action inside the form to control what happens (an ajax/xhr post, not a full http post).

Comment: yeah, this is what I was thinking originally was the issue, I was having some problems with formData and sending the csv over with ajax but I'll figure it out. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out thanks to [Max](https://stackexchange.com/users/361681/max)'s help in the comments.

I was doing a full post request on form submit instead of using ajax to make the request this is why I was being routed out of my ember app and express would just render the response to the upload in the browser.

I installed ember-uploader again which was originally giving me issues because I didn't set the paramName option to match my file input name. Updated code below incase anyone else is running into a similar issue.

Ember HBS Template:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
  <h2 class="toolTitle">Reactivate SKUs</h2>
  <p class="lead">CSV Should Contain 1 Column (SKU) Only</p>
  <p class="lead flash-msg"></p>
  {{file-upload id="upload" url="/tools/sku/reactivate" class="center-block" name="csvdata"}}
</div>
```

file-upload.js (ember-uploader component)

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 
import EmberUploader from 'ember-uploader';

export default EmberUploader.FileField.extend({
  filesDidChange: function(files) {
    const uploader = EmberUploader.Uploader.create({
      url: this.get('url'),
      paramName: 'csvdata'
    });

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(files));
      // this second argument is optional and can to be sent as extra data with the upload
      uploader.upload(files[0]).then(data => {
        $('#upload').fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $('.flash-msg').text(data);
          $('.flash-msg').fadeIn('slow');
        });
      }, error => {
          $('.flash-msg').text('Error uploading file please contact Jay: ' + error);
          $('.flash-msg').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

express router

```
var quotes = require('../api/quote');
var cors = require('cors');
var sku = require('../api/tools/sku');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var util = require("util");
var fs = require("fs"); 

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}

module.exports = function(router){
    router.route('/quotes').post(cors(corsOptions),function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        quotes.addQuote(req,res);
    }).get(cors(corsOptions),function(req,res){
        quotes.getAllQuotes(req,res);
    });
    router.route('*').get(cors(corsOptions), function(req,res){
        res.sendFile('public/index.html',{root:'./'});
    });
    router.route('/tools/sku/reactivate').post(upload.single('csvdata'),function(req,res){
        console.log('handing request over to sku.reactivate');
        sku.reactivate(req,res);
    });
};
```

express api function module:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var csv = require('csv-parse');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

//mysql setup
const connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'rugs_remote2',
        password : 'ofbiz',
        database : 'rugs_prd2',
        multipleStatements: true
    }
);

connection.connect();

module.exports.reactivate = function(req,res){
    //define mysql query function for once readStream emits end event
    function reactivationQuery(arr){
        const queryString = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET SALES_DISCONTINUATION_DATE = NULL WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (?)";
        connection.query(queryString,arr,function(err,rows,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error running sku.reactivate module error is: '+err);
                res.json(err);
            }
            res.json('Successfully reactivated '+rows.changedRows+' SKUs');
        });
    }

    //define array for holding csv data in this case skus
    const skuArray = [];
    //define filesystem readstream from uploaded file
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path).pipe(csv());
    //push csv data to array ignoring headers to skuArray
    readStream.on('data', function(chunk){
        if(chunk[0] !== 'SKU'){
            skuArray.push(chunk[0]);
        }
    });
    //error handling
    readStream.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file stream [ERROR] '+ err);
        res.json('Error while processing file');
    });
    //once read is finished map skuArray to usable string for IN Clause
    readStream.on('end',function(){
       let stringifyArray = skuArray;
       stringifyArray = [stringifyArray]; 
       reactivationQuery(stringifyArray);
    });

}
```